# Using VFR Reader, no toolbar items are shown in UIToolbar

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uitoolbar, vfr-reader

I use the VFR Reader for iOS in Xcode 7 with Swift 2.0 via the Objective-C Bridge like this:

```
var document:ReaderDocument? = ReaderDocument(filePath: szLibraryDirectory + "/test.pdf", password: "")
if(document != nil){
    var readerViewController:ReaderViewController  = ReaderViewController(readerDocument: document)
    readerViewController.delegate = self ;
    readerViewController.modalTransitionStyle = .CrossDissolve;
    readerViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .FullScreen;
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
    self.presentViewController(readerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    readerViewController.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
}
```

My problem is:

when the ViewController shows up there are not items in the UIToolbar (for e. g. the Thumbnails, Printing, etc.)

Example:

[image]

Is there a property to activated the uitoolbar items of vfr-reader?

Answer (score 5):

If you downloaded your vfrReader from cocoapods, That's happened because of a problem with the icons path in the libraries. to solve it just copy the icons  (from the library in GitHup or you will find it in this path : pods/vfrReader/Resources ) to your Assets folder in the project. It should be working fine.